# player.loadVideoById() loads video from same point every time

Tags: youtube-api

When making multiple calls to the YouTube API method player.loadVideoById() with the same videoId and different startSeconds, the video will continue to start from the startSeconds time first specified.

For example, if I run player.loadVideoById({videoId:vID, startSeconds:startTime}) the video will load and play from startTime as requested. However, if I execute this statement again and change the startTime parameter, the video will load from the startTime I first specified. I have run this command manually with no variables for the vID and the startTime so I can rule out the idea that my input variables simply aren't changing.

Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: This sounds like https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4556